# How does the chrome extension evoke the local file explorer and view files by file path?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I don't know if I'm describing my requirements accurately, so I'll tell you what my plugin is trying to do so that I can understand it.

I've developed a chrome extension that takes screenshots and records them, and I'd like to have a history feature.

and on the right side of each history file there is a button to open the file.

It's similar to the one that comes with chrome.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJAgm.png)

I don't have any ideas.

Comment: Use [the new File System API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/capabilities/web-apis/file-system-access).